# Why is drawing an 8bit texture with OpenGL drawing black pixels instead of transparent?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rendering, transparency

**OpenGL Setup:**

```
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glEnable( GL_CULL_FACE );
glCullFace( GL_BACK );
glClearColor( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
```

**Initializing the texture:**

```
// 16x16 X pattern
uint8_t buffer[ 16*16 ] =
{
    255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255,
    0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0,
    0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0,
    0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0,
    255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255,
};

GLuint texture_id;
glGenTextures( 1, &texture_id );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id );
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 16, 16, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
```

The textures are drawn as quads using glBegin/glEnd. The color for each vertex is white with full alpha: {r=255,g=255,b=255,a=255}.

Here's an example scene. The photo and cheese are both loaded from PNG images. The cheese has transparent holes, which show the photo and background behind it. The X pattern I expected to be transparent too:

[image: Example]

Why is the quad black instead of transparent, any how can I fix my code to draw what I was expecting?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680125/can-i-use-a-grayscale-image-with-the-opengl-glteximage2d-function) may be similar, but so far I am unable to apply the brief answer to my current problem.

Update: I think I solved it, thanks to the answers below. I changed...

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 16, 16, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
```

to

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, 16, 16, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
```

... which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Dietrich Epp's answer was almost correct, only that the format you're looking for is GL_ALPHA:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA8, 16, 16, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

Then set the blend function to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` or `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`, depending on if your values are premultiplied. Last but not least set the texture environment to GL_MODULATE

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

Now you can set the color of the 'X' with glColor.

Another approach is not using blending but alpha testing.

Answer (score 3):

Becuse luminance is color, and transparency (alpha) is not color.

If you want transparency, use different format - GL_LUMANANCE_ALPHA or something similar, and store transparency in different channel.

Also, this is already explained in [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml).

> **GL_LUMINANCE**
>
> Each element is a single luminance value. The GL converts it to floating point, then assembles it into an RGBA element by replicating the luminance value three times for red, green, and blue **and attaching 1 for alpha**. Each component is then multiplied by the signed scale factor GL_c_SCALE, added to the signed bias GL_c_BIAS, and clamped to the range [0,1] (see glPixelTransfer).

--edit--

> Any way to keep the 8bit per pixel and achieve the same effect?

I think you could "tell" to OpenGL that initial image is indexed color and then set up proper RGBA palette (where for every element R==G==B==A==index). See [`glPixelTransfer`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelTransfer.xml) and [`glPixelMap`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelMap.xml) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I used GL_LUMINACE as that's what the linked question appeared to suggest. Any way to keep the 8bit per pixel and achieve the same effect?

Comment: @DrTwox: Well, I think you could "tell" to OpenGL that initial image is indexed color and then set up proper RGBA palette (where for every element R==G==B==A==index). I haven't done that myself, though. See glPixelTransfer and glPixelMap for details.

Answer (score 3):

Change `GL_RGBA8` (which makes a grayscale image with **no alpha channel**) to `GL_INTENSITY`:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_INTENSITY, 16, 16, 0,
             GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

The `GL_RGBA8` format, created from `GL_LUMINANCE`, gives pixels of the form `(Y, Y, Y, 1)`, but `GL_INTENSITY` with `GL_LUMINANCE` gives `(Y, Y, Y, Y)`.

You will also want to change your blend mode to assume premultiplied alpha, e.g. change

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

to:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

**Alternative:**

You can also use `GL_ALPHA`, and then use your ordinary blending mode for non-premultiplied alpha:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, 16, 16, 0,
             GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

**Alternative #2:**

You can keep using `GL_LUMINANCE`, and change the blending mode.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

This has the drawback that you can't color the texture without using something like `glBlendColor` (which is not part of the OpenGL headers that ship with MSVC, so you have to use GLEW or something like that):

```
glBlendColor(...);
glBlendFunc(GL_CONSTANT_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);
```

**Alternative #3:**

Use OpenGL 3, and change your fragment shader to handle single-channel textures in the desired way.

Comment: I tried those suggestions; instead of a black box with a white X I just get a white box.

Comment: GL_INTENSITY is not supported as texture format. That's why it's white.

Answer (score 0):

Eight bit images do not use colours, they have a colour palette.  Zero represents index 0 of the colour palette for that image, which will contain 256 colours.  Eight bit images do not have an alpha channel for transparency.  The PNG image you used has an alpha channel.  It would be a 32bit image which has 8 bits for red,  8 bits for green, 8 bits for blue (24bits for colour) and 8 bits for alpha.  You're mixing the two formats.