# How do I display a grayscale image with opengl texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create a texture to display. I have wxh array in which each pixel is 1 byte. I have looked at [Can I use a grayscale image with the OpenGL glTexImage2D function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680125/can-i-use-a-grayscale-image-with-the-opengl-glteximage2d-function) but I am not sure as to how to currently implement it. It looks like the GL_LUMINANCE is deprecated and I need to process the single channel independently . I am not sure how I should try this

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image_width, image_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
```

I tried changing GL_RGBA to other formats like GL_R https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml. I still cannot get the image to display. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you you have a source texture with 1 color channel, then you can use the format `GL_RED` and the base internal format `GL_RED`:

```c
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, image_width, image_height,
             0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
```

Set the texture parameters `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G` and `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B` (see [`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)) to read the green and blue color from the red color channel, too:

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_G, GL_RED);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_B, GL_RED);
```

---

Note, possibly [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) has to be set to 1, when the image is loaded to a texture object:

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, ...);
```

By default the parameter is 4. This means that each line of the image is assumed to be aligned to a size which is a multiple of 4. If the image data is tightly packed then the alignment has to be changed.

---

If you use shader program, then the same can be achieved by [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling). e.g.:

```c
vec3 color = texture(u_texture, uv).rrr;
```